# AWK - using element on next record GETLINE?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I got some problem with this basic data:

```
DP;DG
67;
  ;10
  ;14
  ;14
  ;18
  ;18
  ;22
  ;65
68;
  ;0
  ;9
  ;25
  ;25
70;
```

that I'd like to transform on this kind of output:

```
DP;DG
67;
  ;10
  ;14
  ;14
  ;18
  ;18
  ;22
  ;65;x
68;
  ;0
  ;9
  ;25
  ;25;x
70;
```

The "x" value comes if on the next line $1 exists or if $2 is null. From my understanding, I've to use getline but I don't get the way!
I've tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file2=tmp.csv
file3=fin.csv

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}

{
    print $0;
    getline;
    if($2="") {print $0";x"}
    else {print $0}

}' $file2 > $file3
```

Seemed easy. I don't mention the result, totally different from my expectation.

Some clue? Is getline necessary on this problem?

OK, I continue to test some code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file2=tmp.csv
file3=fin.csv

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}

{
    getline var
    if (var ~ /.*;$/) {
        print $0";x";
        print var;
        }
    else {
        print $0;
        print var;
        }

}' $file2 > $file3
```

It's quite better, but still, all lines that should be marked aren't... I don't get why...

Comment: `From my understanding, I've to use getline`. No, read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to use awk and read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to learn the few times it is appropriate to use getline and all the caveats and reasons not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative one pass version

```
$ awk -F\; 'NR>1 {printf "%s\n", (f && $2<0?"x":"")} 
                 {f=$1<0; printf "%s", $0} 
            END  {print ""}' file
```

Comment: I think OP wants an x when `$2<0` on the next line, and should be stored in the boolean `f`as well. The approach of printing the `x\n` when processing the second line is clever and makes my (not posted) approach of `tac | awk ... | tac` ridiculous. Note that sometimes you want to append `;x\n`.

Answer (score 1):

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{if($1>0||!$2)a[NR-1];next}FNR in a{$0=$0";x"}7' file file
```

or

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{if($1~/\S/||$2).....
```